# Sqlite 3 database is locked

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to use tkinter to make a simple python app.
In the code, I am using sqlite3 databse to store user data which will be containing user data which will be containing username, password, subject, homework_name and due_date.

Below is the code for tracker1.py:
This is how the table is created:

```
def initialize_database():
    # Connect to the database or create a new one if it doesn't exist
    conn = sqlite3.connect("user_data.db")

    # Create a cursor object to execute SQL commands
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Create the table if it doesn't exist
    cursor.execute(
        """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            username TEXT,
            password TEXT,
            subject TEXT,
            homework_name TEXT,
            due_date TEXT
        )
    """
    )

    # Commit the changes and close the connection
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

# Call the initialize_database() function to create or verify the database and table
initialize_database()
```

Neext, the username and password will be stored in the databse once registered:

```
def register_user():
    # Retrieve the username and password entered by the user
    username_info = username.get()
    password_info = password.get()
    
    # Open a connection to the database
    conn = sqlite3.connect("user_data.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Insert the user data into the table
    cursor.execute(
        """
        INSERT INTO users (username, password)
        VALUES (?, ?)
    """,
        (username_info, password_info),
    )

    # Commit the changes and close the connection
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    # Clear the username and password entry fields
    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)

    # Create a label to display the registration success message
    register_success_label = Label(
        register_screen, text="Registration Successful!", fg="green"
    )
    register_success_label.grid(padx=5)
```

Next, after logged in, the window would close automically and enter another py file using subprocess:

```
 root.withdraw()
        subprocess.call(
            ["python", "tracker2.py", username_verify.get()]
```

Below will be codes for tracker2.py:
On tracker2.py, there would be entries and boxes for user to select the subject, homework_name and due_date.

```
def save():
        subject = chosen_subject.get()
        homework = homework_name.get()
        due = due_date.get()

        # Open a connection to the database
        conn = sqlite3.connect("user_data.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Get the username from the command line arguments
        username = sys.argv[1]

        # Update the user's database row with the new subject, homework name, and due date
        cursor.execute(
            """
            UPDATE users
            SET subject=?, homework_name=?, due_date=?
            WHERE username=?
            """,
            (subject, homework, due, username),
        )

        # Commit the changes and close the connection
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

Initially, I was expecting the homework_name, subject and due_date to be stored on the logged in user's database table column
But, on tracker2.py those details won't be saved as there is an error message saying databse is locked.

The register function was working just fine on tracker1.py and I can;t understand how the error could have occured as two pages are using similar ways to store the datas into the database.

[Here is the image of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOcrj.png)
[This is the Github link to my code](https://github.com/Jed177013/Tkinter-app)

Comment: The "database is locked" error usually means that some other program is already using that database file.

Answer (score 0):

I was going crazy today trying to solve problems with database locked.
This is the code that locked my database:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('db/db.sqlite3')
cur=con.cursor()
query=f"SELECT * FROM data_temp LIMIT 1;"
res=cur.execute(consulta)
con.close()
```

I solved including a line to read the results:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('db/db.sqlite3')
cur=con.cursor()
consulta=f"SELECT * FROM data_temp LIMIT 1;"
res=cur.execute(consulta)
out=res.fetchall()  #<-------
con.close()
```

No idea why this works...anybody knows?

UPDATE:
Martin give me a great answer for this here:
[why a .fetchall() call unlock my sqlite3 database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76647433/why-a-fetchall-call-unlock-my-sqlite3-database)

In summary:
using res.fetchall() I am consuming the result of the query. This signals to SQLite that I have finished working with the results and allows the transaction to be completed, releasing the lock on the database.